# Cómo correr una función cada cierto tiempo en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyserial

Hola buenas tengo un pequeño problema, mi programa capta señales de un puerto serial y lo pone en una etiqueta de tkinter. El problema  es que, la señal es de una balanza y manda un peso distinto a cada segundo. Traté de usar un bucle while(true) pero la señal se imprime en la terminal demasiado rápido y ni siquiera llega a ponerse en las etiquetas, a los pocos segundos se cuelga. Si alguien sabe de un método alternativo para que la función corra cada cinco segundos o así,gracias. Intenté usar threading y time.sleep pero no funcionó.
Edit: Al final usé un bucle for y la verdad es que como medida temporal funciona, el problema es que tkinter sigue esperando hasta que termine el bucle para configurar las labels. Aquí dejo el código, si alguien sabe cómo corregir esto, gracias. aquí dejo el código:

```
ventana=customtkinter.CTk()
ventana.geometry("700x500")



#Marco de señales
marco_señales=customtkinter.CTkFrame(ventana)
marco_señales.grid()

#función de control
señal1=IntVar(value=1)



#Función del puerto serial
def captar_señal(puerto):   
    timer=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
    for time in timer:
        señal=serial.Serial(puerto, 9600, timeout=5)
        global datos
        datos=señal.readline()
        numeros="[0-9]+.?[0-9]"
        var1=str(re.findall(numeros, str(datos)))
        var2="Kg."
        label.configure(text=str(datos))
        label2.configure(text="{} {}".format(var1, var2))
        señal.close()
        print(datos)
        
        

label=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco_señales, text="", fg_color="white", text_font=("Arial Black", 16), text_color="black", width=250, height=80)
label.grid(column=0, row=0, pady=5, padx=5)
label2=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco_señales, text="", fg_color="white", text_font=("Arial Black", 16), text_color="black", width=250, height=80)
label2.grid(column=0, row=1,pady=5, padx=5)

#Puertos
def puerto(*args):
   captar_señal(puertos.get())
        
    

label_puertos=customtkinter.CTkLabel(marco_señales, text="Puerto: ")
label_puertos.grid(column=0, row=2,pady=5, padx=5)
valores=["COM1","COM2","COM3","COM4","COM5"]
puertos=customtkinter.CTkComboBox(marco_señales, values=valores, command=puerto)
puertos.grid(column=1, row=2,pady=5, padx=5)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Aparte de la respuesta de más abajo, el programa se te cuelga porque entra en un bucle `while` infinito: no termina nunca...

Answer (score 0):

Yo recuerdo que en otros lenguajes esto es habitualmente implementado a través de una clase Timer.

La función Timer(temporizador), ejemplo:

```
import threading
def f():
    print("¡Hola, mundo!")
# Ejecutar la función luego de 3 segundos.
t = threading.Timer(3, f)
t.start()
print("Esto se ejecuta antes que la función f().")
```

Comment: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/ejecutar-un-codigo-cada-determinado-tiempo/ de aquí lo saque, para mas información

Comment: Lo hice así:#Función del puerto serial
'def captar_señal(puerto):   
    
        señal=serial.Serial(puerto, 9600, timeout=5)
        global datos
        datos=señal.readline()
        numeros="[0-9]+.?[0-9]"
        print(datos)
        señal.close()
        label.configure(text=str(datos))
        label2.configure(text=str(re.findall(numeros, str(datos)))+"Kg")
        time.sleep(5)
        
        



#Puertos
def puerto(*args):
    t = threading.Timer(5, captar_señal(puertos.get()))
    t.start() '

Comment: Y te funciona bien?

Comment: Lo hice así, corre la primera vez y luego el programa se cuelga. Y la terminal arroja:  TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: Mírate el enlace que puse, ahí lo hacen para que sea repetido